# idangerous swiper appending dynamic slide issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel, swiper.js

I am implementing the idangerous swiper and am running into an issue. I am using this for a product image slider. Basically the user swipes through product shots. I needed to add a piece of code that updates the first image when the user clicks a color swatch on the page.

This was my idea:

On click of the swatch, I update the first image in the slider with the url of the correct color.

```
$product_imageTest = $('.swiper-wrapper').first().find("img")
```

Then

```
function HandleColorClick(){
    $product_imageTest.attr('src',colorObj.hoverImage + (productObj.isUITesting ?  "&wid=458&hei=616" :  ""));
}
```

After the image source is updated, I to the first slide of the slider:

```
$(".swatch").click(function(){
     mySwiper.slideTo(1, 400, true);
});
```

All of this works great. Then I found a bug. When I swipe all the way through each image from beginning to end, the next time around the first image will display the original image (not color updated). When I start to swipe to the next slide, the image updates back to the color updated version. At that point I can go back and forth between seeing the original and the updated version.

Comment: Are you dealing with `infinite-swipe` ?

Comment: @Rayon yes I am. The users can continuously swipe through the entire carousel.

Comment: Set `observer : true` while initializing..

Comment: @Rayon I tried that, but no luck.

Comment: Can you share the demo ?

Comment: i have the same issue any resolution?